# Is there a way to use function to draw a square with a minimum size over densest region of points?

Tags: python, arrays, data-visualization, scatter-plot, kdtree

## The Problem:

Using NumPy, I have created an array of random points within a range.

```python
import numpy as np
min_square = 5
positions = (np.random.random(size=(100, 2)) - 0.5) * 2 * container_radius
```

Where `container_radius` is an integer and `min_square` is an integer.

---

Following that, using matplotlib, I plot the points on a graph.

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(positions[:, 0], positions[:, 1], 'r.')
plt.show()
```

This graph shows me the distribution of the points in relation to each other.

---

What I am looking for is a method to implement something similar to or exactly a k-d tree to draw a rectangle over the densest area of the scatter plot with a defined minimum for the size.
This would be done using `plt.gca().add_patch(plt.Rectangle((x, y), width=square_size, height=square_side, fill=None` where `square_side` is the defined by the density function and is at least a minimum sizeo of `min_square`.

## Attempts to Solve the Problem:

So far, I have created my own sort of density function that is within my understanding of Python and easy enough to code without lagging my computer too hard.
The solve comes in the form of creating an additional predefined variable `intervals` which is an integer.
Using what I had so far, I define a function to calculate the densities by checking if the points are within a range of floats.

```python
# clb stands for calculate_lower_bound
def clb(x):
    return -1 * container_radius + (x * 2 * container_radius - min_square) / (intervals - 1)

# crd stands for calculate_regional_density
def crd(x, y):
    return np.where(np.logical_and(\
        np.logical_and(positions[:, 0] >= clb(x), positions[:, 0] < clb(x) + min_square),\
        np.logical_and(positions[:, 1] >= clb(y), positions[:, 1] < clb(y) + min_square)))[0].shape[0]
```

Then, I create a NumPy array of size  `size=(intervals, intervals)` and pass the indices of the array (I have another question about this as I am currently using a quite inefficient method) as inputs into `crd(x,y)` and store the values in another array called `densities`. Then using some method, I calculate the maximum value in my `densities` array and draw the rectangle using some pretty straightforward code that I do not think is necessary to include here as it is not the problem.

## What I Looking For:

I am looking for some function, `f(x)`, that computes the dimensions and coordinates of a square encompassing the densest region on a scatterplot graph. The function would have access to all the variables it needs such as `positions`, `min_square`, etc. If you could use informative variable names or explain what each variable means, that would be a great help as well.

### Other (Potentially) Important Notes:

I am looking for something that gets the job done in a reasonable time. In most scenarios, I am going to be working with around 10000 points and I need to calculate the densest region around 100 times so the function needs to be efficient enough so that the task completes within around 10-20 seconds.
As such, approximations using formulas like the example I have shown are completely valid as long as they implement well and are able to grow the dimensions of the square larger if necessary.

---

Thanks!

Comment: I am finding it hard to understand your problem due to several contradictions.  Are you trying to make a rectangle, or a square. You have used both words. Is it a "fixed-size" as you said in the title, or just a minimum size as stated later?

Comment: It seems to me that your description of your objective is not very well defined.  Since we are talking about a scatterplot of points, "density" only makes sense when considering a region, the size and shape of that region could be anything.  Do you simply want to find a square that contains the maximum possible number of points?  If so, you'll need to define a maximum size, and keep in mind that more than 1, or infinitely many possible squares could contain the same maximum number

Comment: In case you don't know much about the density or the number of points you want to have in the rectangle, have a look at cluster detection algorithms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Yes, you are right. My question title created some contradictions. I have edited the question so that it is more understandable. Regarding your second comment, density in my case means the quotient of the number of points in the region divided by the size of the region. A minimum size would be necessary so that the square is not just going over one point. The trouble, as you mention, arises because there are infinitely many squares but I am looking for an algorithm that can mitigate that by doing some clever mathematical analysis.